# Coded UI Testing in IE - How to upload a file?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

With our CUIT tests in Visual Studio we have the problem that we cannot record the Browser Button action in IE. We just get:

C:\fakepath\Document1.txt

But this obviously does not lead to the real document in a playback. And it's not possible to just type the path into the Browse text field anymore.

Just FYI: This applies to the Coded UI Testing Framework in Visual Studio 2010 Feature Pack 2. The recorder only works with IE.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, turns out I can edit the value "C:\fakepath\Document1.txt" manually in the uitest UIMaps file and change it to a real path. And it works in the reply like this.

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to access the file upload control is supposed to be a security feature. I guess you need to step out of your environment and into the windows environment to accomplish anything.

If you use a macro recorder that can playback from command line (like http://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/versionhistory/) or a similar means, you may be able to record the missing step here (like a simple tab key hit - provided you have focused on the control before the upload control -, a typed text, and another tab key hit) and start the resulting "batch". Or you can even record a mouse click.

However, *if* this test runs in other browsers (if I understand you correctly), wouldn't it be safe enough to assume that it runs in IE as well, because after all you are using a standard control?

Comment: Makes sense. It's the recorder that comes with Visual Studio 2010 Coded UI Testing Framework. The recorder only works with IE. The code does not work in other Browser. The problem is that I cannot enter anything in the Input Box. I've tried to just use it with the keyboard, but everything the recorder stores, is just the fakepath at the end :-(